# Word- VBA- how to clear/reset all content controls in a specific table?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

The following code works to clear all rich text and reset all drop down `CCs` in the entire document

How can I apply this only to the CCs nested in `table(4)`?

```
    Dim oCC As ContentControl
    Dim oCCs As ContentControls
    
    Set oCCs = ActiveDocument.ContentControls
    
    For Each oCC In oCCs
        With oCC
            If oCC.Type = wdContentControlText Then
                .Range.Text = ""
            
            ElseIf oCC.Type = wdContentControlDropdownList Then
                .Type = wdContentControlText
                .Range.Text = ""
                .Type = wdContentControlDropdownList
            End If
        End With
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

`Set oCCs = ActiveDocument.ContentControls`

To:

`Set oCCs = ActiveDocument.Tables(4).Range.ContentControls`